# Setting up Phoenix 1.4 + Webpack + Zurb Foundation

Tags: webpack, zurb-foundation, phoenix-framework

How do I setup Zurb Foundation css framework on Phoenix 1.4 + Webpack?
Unfortunately I have not been able to find any example anywhere ...

mix phx.server starts fine without errors with webpack running, but I do not see zurb foundation css/js being loaded in my app.js/app.scss ...

**Package.json**

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.18",
    "mdn-polyfills": "^5.17.0",
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html",
    "phoenix_live_view": "file:../deps/phoenix_live_view",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^6.0.0",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.5.3",
    "what-input": "^5.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
    "webpack": "4.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4"
  }
}
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
//const foundation = require('foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  entry: {
    './js/app.js': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js']),
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
    externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    foundation: 'Foundation'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, 'js')],
      extensions: ['.js'],
      alias: {
        foundation: 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.core'
      }
    },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }]),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery"
}),
  ]
});
```

**app.js**

```
import LiveSocket from "phoenix_live_view"

let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live")
liveSocket.connect()

import css from "../css/app.scss"

// webpack automatically bundles all modules in your
// entry points. Those entry points can be configured
// in "webpack.config.js".
//
// Import dependencies
//
import "phoenix_html"
```

Comment: Same problem, it was much easier to set it up with Bootsrtap 4 by following [this](https://experimentingwithcode.com/using-bootstrap-and-sass-in-phoenix/) tutorial, but I'm still stuck with Foundation 6.5.3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

1. Install:

   - `node-sass": "^4.12.0"`
   - `sass-loader": "^8.0.0"`
   - `"autoprefixer": "^9.6.4"`
   - `"foundation-sites": "^6.5.3"`
   - `"jquery": "^3.4.1"`
   - `"what-input": "^5.2.6"`

either with `npm` or `yarn` (I used yarn).

2. Check to use `"webpack": "4.41.1"` version, I saw cases where people had some issues with previous versions.
3. Rename `assets/css/app.css` to `assets/css/app.scss` and put the following lines in it:

```
@import "~foundation-sites/scss/foundation";
@include foundation-everything();
```

4. Modify `assets/app.js` as follows:

```
import $ from 'jquery'

require   ('what-input');
window.$ = $;


import Foundation from 'foundation-sites';
$(document).foundation();

import css from "../css/app.scss"
import "phoenix_html"
```

5. Modify `webpack.cpnfig.js` as follows:

   - add `const webpack = require('webpack');` in the top of the file right after other declared constants:
   - in `modules/rules` section, modify the line regarding css and loaders:

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

- in `pligins section, add the following line to use`jQuery`:

```
plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer'),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }]),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ // inject modules as global vars
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery', 'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    })
  ]
```

6. Modify the main layout `../templates/layout/app.html.eex` to use `Foundation` styles as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Storex · Phoenix Framework</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="top-bar-left">
          <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
            <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
            <li class="has-submenu">
              <a href="#0">One</a>
              <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
                <li><a href="#0">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="top-bar-right">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
            <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="grid-container fluid">
      <%= unless is_nil(get_flash(@conn, :info)) do %>
        <p class="success label" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :info) %></p>
      <% end %>
      <%= unless is_nil(get_flash(@conn, :error)) do %>
        <p class="alert label" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :error) %></p>
      <% end %>
      <%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

7. Start the server with `mix phx.server` and check the browser console, - you will have some warnings and the page should have Foundation styles.

You cab find the source code [here.](https://github.com/belgoros/storex)

Hope this helps.